# How can i stop git from tracking a folder?

Tags: git, directory, tracking

i got a short problem with git. I found out that git is like tracking my C:\Users\name folder, where name is a placeholder. Because when i am at C:\Users\name and say git status it tells me:
'''untracked files [...] nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track) '''
How can i say git that it should **not** track my users folder?
I read something about .gitignore, but i think this is not working, because i dont want to whole folder to be tracked from git.

Comment: git only tells you that in a directory which is actually a git repository, so that may imply your user homefolder was turned into one by accident. You can verify this by checking if the directory has a **.git** subdirectory. Simply removing that subdirectory should be enough to make git forget all about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## C:\Users\name_here?

If `git` is trying to track your user folder it means that the root of the ropository is in location which has your user folder as its subirectory. This could be `C:\Users` or `C:\`.

You need to copy your repository to a dedicated folder e.g. `C:\git\Project1`. Please be aware that if you are moving files, you need to move the hidden `.git` folder. (`.git` folder makes a folder a git reposiotry).

If you're confused, it may be easiest to start in a new folder.

---

## To ignore a folder in `git`

You can use a `.gitignore` file.

The [doco](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore

To ignore a folder use `dir_to_ignore/`

Please note that `.gitignore` should be part of the repository.

1. Create a text file called `.gitignore` at the root of the repository
2. Add `folder_to_ignore/` to it (please note the slash at the end.
3. `git add .gitignore`
4. `git commit 'Adding .gitignore'`

Comment: but how exactly should i do it then? Can you give me an example? And why is my git tracking the Users folder?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to tymtam's answer, I want to add that if the git is already tracking the directory, adding the .gitignor file will not help and you should use the *"git rm"* command so that the git stops tracking the file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by deleting the.git Folder. But the folder was hidden and therefore in havent seem it